# How from Firebase get next data in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, firebase, xcode7

I want to get next KEY from current data.
So I have:

```
{
    "Key1":"Value1",
    "Key2":"Value2",
    "Key3":"Value3"               
  }
```

And I can get it with this code:

```
let historyUrl = firebase.childByAppendingPath("Data")

historyUrl.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
            historyValue in 
            print(historyValue.value)
        })
```

How get separate values in Key1, Key2, Key, when I don't know name of KEY's, and without decoding json?

Answer (score 2):

You can always get the key and value from a snapshot

for value:

```
print(historyValue.value)
```

for key:

```
print(historyValue.key)
```

when using .value, it will read in the entire contents of the parent node. You can then iterate over the snapshot to get the individual key:value pairs

```
for child in historyValue.children {
  print(child.key)
  print(child.value)
}
```

Another option is to use .childAdded, which will iterate over each individual child one at a time, and then again any time a new child is added.

```
ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { historyValue in
    println(historyValue.key)
    println(historyValue.value)
})
```